# How does racial spell casting interact with spell casting class levels?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, monsters

Some creatures explicitly cast spells as an Nth-level $class, such as Nymphs. What happens if such a creature takes class levels in that class? Do the class levels stack, are separate spell lists generated as though a different spell casting class had been taken, or what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless otherwise noted, you can assume racial casting levels stack.  You'll find the rule to that effect, among other places, in the section on monster advancement [here:](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/monster-advancement/)

> If the creature possesses class features (such as spellcasting or sneak attack) for the class that is being added, these abilities stack.

It's worth noting that this only applies for spellcasting; spell-like abilities are, unless otherwise noted, cast at a set level. If no caster level is given, then you can refer to the general rules on [spell-like abilities](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Spell-Like-Abilities-Sp-), which defaults to the class level they are gained at.
For monsters, the default caster level is instead equal to their [hit dice.](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Spell-Like-Abilities-Sp-)

Comment: Ooh, good point. I'll add that to the answer.